# Rails: invite to sign up as friend with devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise in my Rails App. I want user can give a link to their friends, and through the link, they can sign up and then become friends with their inviter.

Here is what I come up with.

First, I give every user a unique code, like `dbgadf34t42a`, and people could visit url like `localhost/signup?invite_code=dbgadf34t42a`. Then customize Devise's `sign up controller`, use this code to find the inviter and then create the `friendship` relationship.

Code would be something like

```
  def create
    #Create user account, and then create Friendship
    invite_code = paramsp[:invite_code]
    if user.save
      inviter = User.find_by_invite_code(invite_code)
      inviter.friendships.create(friend: user)
    end
  end
```

I'm wondering

1. If there is any better way of doing this, gems or codes.
2. I didn't find good resources on customize Devise's `Signup Controller`, can I extract the logic to another place, store the invite code, and then continue creating `friendship` model?

Perhaps something like:

```
  def after_sign_up
    if params[:invite_code]
      redirect_to new_friendship_path
    else
      # default_behavior
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If there is any better way of doing this, gems or codes.

You may use [devise-inviteable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) gem. For friendship create you can customize this gem.

> 2. I didn't find good resources on customize Devise's Signup Controller, can I extract the logic to another place, store the invite code, and then continue creating friendship model?

To customise Devise Signup you need to inherit Devise::RegistrationsController

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   def create
     super
     # Now write your customize code for friendship
   end
end
```

And then tell devise to use that controller instead of the default with:

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Comment: That is for invite via email. But I don't need email. User can just send a link to another to invite them. The important thing is handling create `Friendship` when user sign up.